# Renaming coordinates d.x and d.y in D3 hierarchy layouts

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to display multiple D3 hierarchy layouts simultaneously, using the same data-set. This is working out fine, except for the fact that each layout computes and re-computes coordinates named `d.x` and `d.y` with different values, and this creates conflicts when updating any of the charts.

Is it possible to override (rename?) `d.x` and `d.y` as one can override `children/values` in the following example???

```
    var tree = d3.layout.tree()
             .children(function(d) {
                 return d.values;
             });
```

I've been draining my brain on this one... thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is something set by the layout that you cannot override without changing the source code. You can however use copies of the same data with different layouts.

Comment: That's what I suspected, thanks. I wanted to avoid loading the client side with multiple copies of thousands of entries.